# Why am I getting error when trying to alter session using a bind variable

Tags: oracle

I can't find any Oracle docs that forbid using bind variables in 'alter session', but it doesn't work:

```
declare
savedecim char(2);
begin
savedecim := ',.';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DECLARE foo char(2); BEGIN foo := :1; END;' using savedecim; -- works
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER session SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'''; -- works
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER session SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = :1' using savedecim; -- ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
null;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind variables are not allowed in DDL statements. Hence the error.

According to Tom Kyte,

"DDL btw is not in the shared pool, therefore, bind variable = not used for DDL as it is not 
shareable."

Comment: So, anything requiring 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' in a PL/SQL block is DDL, right?

Comment: execute immediate statement is for dynamic sql. It could be any type of sql statements